# What exactly does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Consider the violinist Jascha Heifetz, known for his blank expression when performing. A 1925 article remarked on his deportment: "Cold, calm, dispassionate, he stands on the platform and performs miracles of dexterity, displays his beauties of tone. *But do we not feel slightly chilled, anxious perhaps for less mastery and more humanity?*

Does the last sentence mean a. we feel chilled and want humanity more than dexterity. or b. what really makes us chilled and anxious is his humanity rather than his mastery.?

Comment: Paragraph (and critical sentence) is (are) missing.

Comment: Not really an answer, but Jascha Heifetz was widely regarded as the most perfect violinist, perhaps of all time, but people turned to Kreisler or Milstein when they wanted music rather than plain virtuosity. This is what I've read, not necessarily my views.

Answer (score 4):

If you're *anxious **for** something*, it normally means you want it, but you're afraid/anxious you won't get it. In this case it's a fairly "flowery" usage, but what the writer means is...

> We feel chilled by the detached/expressionless performance; we'd *much rather* have more "humanity" in it, even if the performer exhibited less "technical mastery".

---

EDIT: Taking account of comments below, I think I should point out that this writer's usage of *anxious **for** [something which is earnestly desired]* sounds dated/formal/"pseudo-erudite" to me.

Today, you're more likely to hear *anxious **about** [something "unresolved" which causes anxiety]*.

Comment: I actually think the word meant was "eager" instead of "anxious".  Though "anxious" is perfectly acceptable in that sentence, the combination of negative connotation and misconstrued meaning lead me to prefer your rewrite or avoidance of that word altogether.

Comment: @Kristina: Actually, it **is** "anxious" - OP didn't give a link, but it was [easy enough to find](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r_p_Q6TUrQoC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22Consider+the+violinist+Jascha+Heifetz%22&source=bl&ots=pVDwbrYMmG&sig=xoEGJHqGDwCe2GtAS6MKezv1l_o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IIK-UezMLcKk0QX28oCADA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Consider%20the%20violinist%20Jascha%20Heifetz%22&f=false). But in this context, *eager, keen, longing, desperate, searching, looking, hoping,* etc. would all do just fine, and effectively convey the same sense.

Comment: Wgat I meant to say was though "anxious" was used, I thought that "eager" (or any of your suggestions) would be a better choice in that context.

Comment: 'Slightly chilled' and 'anxious' do seem to need an 'or perhaps even' rather than a comma between them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's fine to my ear, as if puncuated *chilled?—anxious, perhaps, for ...*

Comment: @StoneyB Your written form is fine - it allows for the sizeable 'contrast of degree' between _slightly chilled_ and _fully anxious_. I don't think the comma allows for such a degree of contrast.

Comment: @Edwin, StoneyB: Maybe "flowery" wasn't the ideal descriptor above. I didn't want to say *grandiloquent, highfalutin, pompous, stilted* (or maybe *dated, antiquated*) because they sound more negative than I'd have intended. Looking at a couple of paragraphs to gauge the writer's prose style, I think we're seeing exactly what he intended to write. *Anxious* isn't a "strengthening" of *chilled* here - it's a more-or-less archaic usage meaning *earnestly desirous of*. Also note that if you link *chilled/anxious* as suggested, it would clash with the following **for**. He's too careful for that!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. The comma is obviously correct then. And Alex Depue and Joshua Bell are my favourite violinists.

Comment: @Edwin: As luck would have it, today's [Guardian crossword](http://www.guardian.co.uk/crosswords/cryptic/25977/print) has just forced me to look up the word [tushery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tushery), which I didn't know before. Arguably, if *anxious for more humanity* doesn't leap out at you as the core element in the sentence, it's because that usage is an example of "tushery".